# Why Juila module have to be prefixed with dot?

Tags: julia

Why module `using .A` has to be **prefixed with dot**? It doesn't work if you omit the dot.

File `./A.jl`

```
module A
  export sayHi
  function sayHi() 
    println("hi")
  end
end
```

File `./Main.jl`

```
include("./A.jl")
using .A # <= Why it has to be prefixed with dot?

sayHi()
```

Running, start REPL and type

```
include("./Main.jl")
```

**Part 2**

And if you move file `A.jl` to different location, like `../some-dir/A.jl` it has to be prefixed to **two dots** `using ..A`. Why?

Answer (score 2):

Because you define module A inside your current module. The dot means "look inside the current module for this". https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/modules/#Relative-and-absolute-module-paths-1

Comment: Thanks. But I don't want to define a module inside of somehow relative to my current module, I want to be able to easily edit it - so it should be a file in my project folder, but it should be used the same as "standard" modules like `using Plots`, how can I do that?

Comment: `]dev /Path/to/MyModule` or `]add /Path/to/MyModule` https://julialang.github.io/Pkg.jl/v1/managing-packages/#Adding-a-local-package-1

Answer (score -5):

After digging it deeper - it seems like the answer is - **don't use modules**.

1. The documentation is wrong, it says

---

[image]

---

When in reality, the module usage is heavily tied to the location of files, it could be `using Foo`, `using .Foo`, `using ..Foo` or `using Main.Foo` - depending on the location of the `Foo` module relative to the file that imports it. In my personal opinion - something is very wrong with that design.

2. No support in the VSCode Editor, it doesn't understand `using ..Foo`. There are other ways to use modules, including altering `startup.jl` or `JULIA_LOAD_PATHS` - none of it works either. I assume nobody noticing these problems because nobody actually using modules.
3. Top answer on YCombinator - gives the same answer - the best way to use modules in Julia - is to not use it at all https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=19232824

Comment: That's definitely not the appropriate conclusion and that part of the documentation is correct. If you want to load a module as if it were a package, then structure it like a package and make sure that it's loadable via the standard code loading mechanisms.